# Using plyr::mapvalues with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, dplyr

`plyr::mapvalues` can be used like this:

```
mapvalues(mtcars$cyl, c(4, 6, 8), c("a", "b", "c"))
```

But this doesn't work:

```
mtcars %>%
dplyr::select(cyl) %>%
mapvalues(c(4, 6, 8), c("a", "b", "c")) %>%
as.data.frame()
```

How can I use `plyr::mapvalues` with `dplyr`? Or even better, what the `dplyr` equivalent?

Comment: Try `mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% .$cyl %>% plyr::mapvalues(c(4,6,8), c('a', 'b', 'c'))%>% as.data.frame()`

Comment: Or `mtcars %>%   mutate(x = mapvalues(cyl, c(4, 6, 8), c("a", "b", "c"))) %>%   select(x)`

Comment: That works. What does `.$cyl` do?

Comment: @luciano It gets the `cyl` as vector.  Usually, the syntax in dplyr is to apply the function inside `mutate` (as Richard Scriven showed), but I was just imitating your code

Comment: Just noticed that renames `cyl` to `.` So this solution only sort of works.

Comment: You could use `mtcars %>% transmute(cyl = factor(cyl, labels = c("a", "b", "c")))` similarly

Comment: @luciano You could change the previous code to `mtcars %>% .$cyl %>% plyr::mapvalues(c(4,6,8), c('a', 'b', 'c')) %>% data.frame(cyl=.)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**2020 Update:**  plyr is now a "retired" package and its official guidance suggests using the actively-improved and maintained dplyr package instead. So it's preferable to use only dplyr, in this case `dplyr::recode()` as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59617319), and avoid plyr entirely.

**To use `plyr::mapvalues()` with dplyr:**

To use it and return a one-column data.frame:

```
mtcars %>%
  transmute(cyl = plyr::mapvalues(cyl, c(4, 6, 8), c("a", "b", "c")))
```

Or if you want a single vector output, like in your working example, use `pull`:

```
mtcars %>%
  pull(cyl) %>%
  plyr::mapvalues(., c(4, 6, 8), c("a", "b", "c"))
```

If you are using both dplyr and plyr simultaneously, see this note from the [dplyr readme](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr):

> You'll need to be a little careful if you load both plyr and dplyr at
> the same time. I'd recommend loading plyr first, then dplyr, so that
> the faster dplyr functions come first in the search path. By and
> large, any function provided by both dplyr and plyr works in a similar
> way, although dplyr functions tend to be faster and more general.

Though note that you can call `mapvalues` using `plyr::mapvalues` if dplyr is loaded without needing to load plyr.

Answer (score 15):

As the questions also mentions

> Or even better, what the dplyr equivalent?

The equivalent is `recode()`.

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_levels_of_a_factor/

```
name <- c("John", "Clara", "Smith")
sex <- c(1,2,1)
age <- c(30,32,54)
df <- data.frame(name,sex,age)
df %>% mutate(sex=recode(sex,
`1`="Male",
`2`="Female"))
```

This will "mapvalues" 1 to Male and 2 to Female.

**UPDATE:**
`recode()` is now superseded in favor of case_match()

Answer (score 7):

I was a heavy `plyr::mapvalues()` user. I used it for replacing old values in strings with new ones. Something like:

```r
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(name = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE))
check_list <- data.frame(old = letters[1:5], new = LETTERS[1:5])

data$name
#> [1] "a" "d" "a" "b" "e" "c" "b" "c" "c" "a" "e" "e" "b" "b"

plyr::mapvalues(data$name, check_list$old, check_list$new)
#> [1] "A" "D" "A" "B" "E" "C" "B" "C" "C" "A" "E" "E" "B" "B" ...
```

Please correct me if I am wrong, but there is not an equally short and tidy `dplyr` way of doing this. You can still do it with `dplyr::recode()`, however:

```r
dplyr::recode(data$name, !!!setNames(check_list$new, check_list$old))
#> [1] "A" "D" "A" "B" "E" "C" "B" "C" "C" "A" "E" "E" "B" "B" ...
```

As it says in [the documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html), the order for the named vector is old (name) = new (value), which is the opposite to `dplyr::mutate()` and `dplyr::rename()` functions (when writing, might have been fixed later).

Adding this as an answer because I keep Googling how to do it when I forget and could not find the answer quickly. Perhaps now I can. The solution is modified from the last two lines of Examples in the function documentation.