# Recoding values with dpylr using a lookup table

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to use the *recode* function of dpylr together with a lookup table (data.frame or list)?

What I would like to have would look something like this:

```
# Recode values with list of named arguments
data <- sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 10, replace = T) 
lookup <- list(a = "Apple", b = "Pear") 
dplyr::recode(data, lookup)
```

I found the *[mapvalues](https://rdrr.io/cran/plyr/man/mapvalues.html)* and *[revalue](https://rdrr.io/cran/plyr/man/revalue.html)* functions from the *plyr* package. Combining them is possible as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013652/using-plyrmapvalues-with-dplyr). 
However, I am wondering whether something similar is possible with *dplyr* only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works like this:

```
dplyr::recode(data, !!!lookup)
```

Also useful with mutate in a dataframe tibble:

```
df <- tibble(code = data)

df %>% 
  mutate(fruit = recode(code, !!!lookup))
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `base R`

```
v1 <- unlist(lookup)[data]
ifelse(is.na(v1), data, v1)
```

Comment: Not a *dplyr* function, but *base R* is ok too.

Answer (score 5):

```
do.call(dplyr::recode, c(list(data), lookup))
```

> ```
> [1] "Pear" "c"    "d"    "c"    "Pear" "Pear" "d"    "c"    "d"    "c"
> ```