# Can you explain how replace function is calculating vector length?

Tags: r, replace, dimensions

I am using replace function to replace numbers with characters in a list but seem to need to add an extra value to the index list for the code to work. (See example)

Simple version of by problem is that I have a list (0,1) and I want to replace 0 with "a" and 1 with "b".

```
replace(0:1, 0:1, c("a","b"))
```

Generates following results

```
[1] "a" "1"
Warning message:
In x[list] <- values :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

when extend index list to 0:2 I get the desired output

```
> replace(0:1, 0:2, c("a","b"))
[1] "a" "b"
```

I obviously don't understand how the replace function works but I can't seem to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: The second argument to `replace` is a list of *indices* (not values) and R uses 1-based indexing. `0:1` only contains 1 valid index.

Comment: @JohnColeman - in the answer box below ↓ ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail I didn't want to simply diagnose the problem but rather wanted to suggest a workaround for what OP was trying to do. Having said that, I think that I do sometimes fall into the habit of answering questions in the comments. Less typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to replace is a list of indices (not values) and R uses 1-based indexing. 0:1 only contains 1 valid index. Thus in effect,

```
replace(0:1, 0:1, c("a","b"))
```

is equivalent to

```
replace(0:1, 1, c("a","b"))
```

which generates the warning message.

It seems that you are really looking for the functionality of [mapvalues](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/mapvalues) from the plyr package. For example,

```
x <- c(2,3,5,7,11)
plyr::mapvalues(x,c(3,7),c(10,12))
```

which leads to the output:

```
[1]  2 10  5 12 11
```

`mapvalues` is an example of a plyr function that doesn't have a direct analog in the newer package dplyr. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28013652/4996248). Using both packages simultaneously is not recommended.  This is why I used the more explicit `plyr::mapvalues()` rather than first `library(plyr)` and then simply `mapvalues()`.